# using Doctrine With laminas project issue : "Class does not exist"

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2, laminas

I just installed Doctrine with my Laminas project. I added a database connection and generated my entities in the Application folder **(Application\Entity)**. I added my entities settings to the module.config.php file in the Application folder. I created a new User and everything, including routing, is working fine. However, when I try to fetch all data from my table to view, the screen displays an error: 'Class '**Application\Entity\User**' does not exist'.
i can't find any solution
module
|_Application
|_config
|_Entity
|_src
|_view
|_User
|_config
|_src
|_view

**entities settings :** namespace : Application
<in Application folder - `module.config.php`>

`````
'doctrine' => [
        'driver' => [
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => [
                'class' => AnnotationDriver::class,
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => [__DIR__ . '/../Entity']
            ],
            'orm_default' => [
                'drivers' => [
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
````

**UserManager** 
```
namespace : User\Manager
```

```
public function listUsers()
    {
        $query = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();
        return $query;
   }
```

**UserController** 
```
namespace : User\Controller
```

```
public function listUserAction()
    {
        $data = $this->usermanager->listUsers();
        var_dump($data);
        die();
        $view = new ViewModel([
            'users' => $data
        ]);
        return $view;
    }
```


`Entity Folder => Path : Application\Entity`
`````

Answer (score 0):

As this question was already answered in the [Laminas forums](https://discourse.laminas.dev/t/using-doctrine-with-laminas-project-issue-class-does-not-exist/3166), I think I should complete this question here, too.

Your folder structure is wrong. The folder where your entities are stored must be a subfolder of the src folder of your application.

`./module/Application/src/Entity/User.php`

In Laminas projects all business logic is stored in the src folder. The Laminas autoloading will try to receive all classes from there.

Comment: that is me too hhhh tank you